# Central error logging service for web applications

Tags: logging, error-handling, web

I'm about to launch a new website and I'm using Pingdom to track the uptime of the site, but I'm interesting in logging any errors generated by the site in a central location. I'd like to put code into my top level exception handler that will package up the exception and send it to another application, which would then generate an email and send it to me.

I will be logging locally of course, but the logs are difficult to get to when I'm out and about. I have the option of writing my own solution to this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something better exists.

Does anyone know of any companies/sites that offer such a service?

If not, would anyone consider this a useful service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airbrake](http://airbrake.io) looks quite promising.  It officially supports Ruby and iOS, and has experimental JavaScript support.  There's also 3rd party plugins for [various other languages](http://help.airbrake.io/kb/api-2/alternate-plugins-widgets-addons-and-extras).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [arecibo](https://github.com/andymckay/arecibo/). It's an open-sourced error logging app.  It has a number of clients libraries (used to log the errors) and can be used in python, php or ruby applications.  The server part is written in python/django and can be run on your own server or on Google's app engine.

Worth a look, we're going to be using it to record application errors across our websites, I think it's in use by Bitbucket and Mozilla as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Loggly](http://loggly.com/) is a nice option - it doesn't (or didn't) have all of the alerting options I'd like last time I looked at it, but I gave a free demo account a spin. Might be worth looking at.

Comment: That does look interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: I just started using Exceptional.Io - it doesn't cover system logs (like from /var/messages, etc) the way Loggly can, but it's been great for devs, since it tracks exceptions and emails when one gets triggered. Def more dev focused than sysadmin focused tho.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'd do myself, but I'm trying to avoid writing more code. I'd like a service that would handle that for me.

Answer (score 0):

[cloud4apps](https://www.cloud4apps.com) has a remote error logging service API and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing with .NET and want some ideas, browse this list of Serilog sinks:

http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=serilog+sinks

Give preference toward services hosted near your servers, especially if you anticipate sending a high volume of fine-grained logs. I also like having the option to choose between TCP and UDP.