# Client side logging using node.js(maybe without modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, logging, error-logging

Is it clever to put a try,catch around my minified java script code and whenever someone gets an error on the client side it will send a `POST` to my server and writes(appends) it into a file on the server file system ?

The problem here I see is security one, everybody could `POST` anything to my server and cause a BufferOverflow or fill it so that nobody else could write to that log file anymore or he could write malicouse code in it !?

What do you think?

Comment: It's not a bad idea; in fact several companies do this exact thing—Sentry, Airbrake, etc. There are also open source tools. This question will be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734446/central-error-logging-service-for-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

Client Errors to server side logging is a good idea if you want to be able to fix client side errors.

Otherwise, you'd be leaning on your own testing to catch all these errors (which you certainly won't). There's a nice blog post with code and video example showing how to implement this.
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm